# ¿Cómo solucionar el error "Expected collections.Iterable, got 'None' instead."?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de python y estoy intentando ordenar una lista de objetos bajo un cierto criterio, pero cuando indico el criterio me sale el error

> Expected collections.Iterable, got 'None' instead`.

Tengo una clase `Prenda`:

```
class Prenda():
    def __init__(self,identificacion,descripcion,precio,stock,tipo):
        self.identificacion = identificacion;
        self.descripcion = descripcion;
        self.precio = precio;
        self.stock = stock;
        self.tipo = tipo;

    def toString(self):
        print("Identificacion: " + str(self.identificacion))
        print("Descripcion: "+self.descripcion)
        print("Precio: $"+str(self.precio))
        if stock > 0:
            print("Cantidad en stock: " +str(self.stock))
        else:
            print("No queda stock")
        print("Tipo de prenda: "+str(self.tipo))
```

Tengo un pequeño código que solicita la cantidad de prendas a cargar y con un ciclo `for` solicito los datos según la cantidad de prendas que ingrese:

```
for x in range(cantidad):
    identificacion = int(input("Identificacion de prenda: "))
    descripcion = input("Descripcion: ")
    precio = float(input("Precio: "))
    stock = int(input("Cantidad en stock: "))
    tipo = int(input("Tipo de prenda (valores entre 0 y 14, con ambos numeros incluidos): "))
    print()
    p = Prenda(identificacion, descripcion, precio, stock, tipo)
    lista.append(p)

    while tipo < 0 or tipo > 14:
        tipo = int(input("Tipo de prenda (valores entre 0 y 14, con ambos numeros incluidos: "))
        p = Prenda(identificacion, descripcion, precio, stock, tipo)
        lista.append(p)
        print()
```

Después de esto intento mostrar los datos de todas las prendas de menor a mayor, según su precio, pero acá es donde obtengo el error:

```
for x in lista.sort(key = x.precio): #<-- aca es donde me sale el error.
    x.toString()
```

También he intentado con:

```
for x in lista.sort(key= lambda prenda: prenda.precio):
    x.toString()
```

Tampoco funciona, si intento ejecutar el código aun con el error, al momento de llegar a la linea donde esta el `.sort()`, me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    for x in lista.sort(key= lambda prenda: prenda.precio):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Intenta imprimir tu lista a ver qué contiene

Comment: tiene los datos que cargue, solamente que me los muestra en el orden que lo cargue y necesito que los ordene por precio.

Comment: Por favor solo añade el código relevante a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `sort()` de las listas **no devuelve** ningún valor, lo que hace es reescribir la lista de manera ordenada.

Cuando haces una expresión de como esta

```
l = [78,56,13,52]

for n in l.sort():
    print(n)
```

La variable toma los valores del retorno de `l.sort()`, osea `None`

```
for n in None:
```

Esto claramente no es válido. Debido a que se espera que `l.sort()` sea un iterable. En su lugar considera ordenar la lista antes de realizar la iteración.

```
l.sort(key)

for i in l:
    #...
```

También puedes usar la función [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

```
for i in sorted(l,key):
    #...
```

En ambos ejemplos `l` es la lista en cuestión, y `key` el argumento que define el método de ordenamiento.